# SQL - Referencing a "replacement" event

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I apologize if the title of this question isn't very clear - I wasn't sure what to name it.

Let's say I'm designing a database that's tracking sensors that are attached to a drone. These sensors sometimes get old and need to be replaced. I want to keep records of these events. I'm keeping track of maintenance records on each sensor. Thus, there's a SensorWork table where I keep track of all the maintenance done on a particular sensor.

I want to track when Sensor A replaces Sensor B - I want to be able to print a record that says "Sensor A replaced Sensor B". So in my SensorWork table I want to keep track of the replacement. But how do I do that? I don't want to store the ids of both of the sensors since both of those are already stored in the DroneSensor table, so including the ids of both the new sensor and the old sensor in the SensorWork table would be redundant. I think the problem arises because ideally I'd like to reference a "replacement event", but the "replacement event" is actually two rows in the DroneSensor table. I know that I could do it by storing the ID of the DroneSensorID and then using the date fields to find the previous sensor. I'll do that if I need to, but I'd like to avoid doing it based on the date fields. Ideally I'd like some way to easily track the sequence of sensors that were measuring a certain property (For example, I'd like to see a historical "sequence" of all the sensors that measured temperature - and I'm assuming that only one sensor will measure temperature at a time.) It'd also be nice to account for the potential scenario that a sensor is removed on one day and not replaced until several days later, so there'd be a short gap in the records. I feel like I might be missing some obvious solution - but maybe I'm not.

Here's a simplified DB diagram:

[image: Simplified DB Diagram]

Any suggestions?

Comment: You could create another table specifically for replacements

Comment: You mean a table with "old sensor" and "new sensor" columns? I could, but that seems redundant. It'd be possible for the new table and the DroneSensor table to have contradicting records. Ideally I'd like to be able to derive it from what I already have.